# svnrdump load not working, (E170001)

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I'm trying to learn the svn tool a little bit better

I dumped our main repository (from our team) via the svnrdump  > outfile.dump
this worked

but if i try to import it into another server i get

```
svnrdump: E170001: Authorization failed
```

The server is running on a linux VM (inside virtualbox)
i create there with svnadmin a empty repository..
and as far as i understand it, I enabled anonymous accesss (its only on the local machine, so no auth should be necassery)

I searched the web for some hints, but I only found issues regarding Windows user rights 
and I'm running a Linux machine (linuxmint and SVN 1.7.10)

any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as far as i understand it, I enabled anonymous accesss

Obviously - not

Anyway, you can (and must really) to use for load data into locally-reachable repository (you have access to FS of repo-host) old good local `svnadmin load`, which ignore all and any access-restriction as **admin-tool**

Comment: Thanks 
I just added anonymous read/write access, know it works
stupid mistake from my site

Answer (score 1):

[`svnrdump load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnrdump) requires you to authenticate and you should have Read / Write access to the repository. The error you get means that you lack access permissions to the repository. Check access permissions for your user account.

See ["Repository data migration using svnrdump"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnrdump).

> The primary difference [from svnadmin dump] is that instead of requiring direct access to
>   the repository, svnrdump operates remotely, using the very same
>   Repository Access (RA) protocols that the Subversion client does. **As
>   such, you might need to provide authentication credentials. Also, your
>   remote interactions are subject to any authorization limitations
>   configured on the Subversion server.**